# Error handling in express while piping stream to response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

I'm having some problem with handling errors in a Express js app.

My problem is that I'm piping a stream to response, and I don't know what is the best method 
to handle error that could occur in the readable stream.

I'm using errorHandler middleware, configured just after route middleware:

```
...
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.errorHandler());
...
```

And this is my route:

```
exports.folders = function(req, res, next) {
    //throw new Error("TEST ERROR");
    var path = decodeURIComponent(req.params.path),
        foldersStream = wd.listFolders(path);

    foldersStream.on("error",function(err){
        console.log("STREAM ERROR")
        console.dir(next.name)
        return next(err);
    });


    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    foldersStream.pipe(res);
};
```

If I throw the `TEST ERROR` in the body of the function, it is handled as expected by express `errorHandler`.

Anyway, if an error event is emitted in the stream, the error event handler get called, because I can see the message in console, but `errorHandler` never get called.

If I don't handle the error event, the whole node process crash. If I handle it, the server send a 500 response to client, but `errorHandler` is not called, so I miss the stack trace in the log.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: By handling it you mean, calling `next(err)`? and also the server sending a 500, is it the plain text message containing only the error message(`Error: ENOENT`) or is it the html page with `express` in h1 and the error in h2?

Comment: By handling I mean, at least, to log the error and close the response.  I know it's not always possible to send 500 status or even to show an html error page, because the error can occur after I sent headers to client or after I start send JSON to it.

Comment: How do you know `errorHandler` is not called?

Comment: Because the response is never closed, and I get no evidence of the error in logs

Comment: I tried many different cases, and always the error gets logged to the console. What version of express are you using?

Comment: @Farid: I too get the error logged to the console, and I also get the "STREAM ERROR" message. My problem is mainly that the error will stop piping the stream to response, and so the response is never ended. The browser is still waiting for the response end, until it timeout. What I want to achieve is at least a way to log to file (not console) that something wrong occur, and at least to close the response, so that the browser stop waiting. Or even better, to send the browser a 500 status to signal the error condition, but I know this is not always possible.

Comment: I searched connect code for a mistake somewhere that might hang the request, but there isn't any. When there is an error, it either destroys the socket or it send a proper 500. Also express/connect don't write logs to files. You should use this: https://npmjs.org/package/express-winston

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try to use winston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct: the problem is that the resonse is partially returned when the error occured.

Once the `folderStream` starts to pipe data into the response, the `errorHandler` is unable to write your stacktrace when invoked by next(err).

In that case, the browser (or http client) received a cancelled response.